# How to solve this integral that comes out to have iota and sinh-1??

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, substitution

This is an integral which I'm unable to solve till now.

$$\int \sqrt{ x + \frac1x}\text{d}x $$

I thought if Wolfram|Alpha solved it I would get some idea of how to solve it, but it gave a really complicated answer for it: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+(x%2B(1%2Fx))%5E0.5

Maybe a substitution so that the squareroot vanishes (i.e. a squared substitution), but that didn't help me either. Any hints on how to solve it? I'd like to try to solve it first before knowing the solution.

Thanks!

Comment: The result is non-elementary. Maybe your teacher made a mistake or is joking with you somehow... Or is it in a course on elliptic functions?

Comment: Its often but true that many teachers at K-12 or college level tried to motivate their students by assigning problems that they dont fully understand if the students can or cannot solve.

Answer (score 3):

If we replace $x$ with $t^2$ we are left with the integral:
$$ 2\int \sqrt{t^4+1}\,dt $$
that can be managed through integration by parts in order to get:
$$ \int\frac{t^4}{\sqrt{1+t^4}}\,dt  = \int\sqrt{1+t^4}\,dt-\int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t^4+1}}$$
so that the problem boils down to computing:
$$ \int\frac{dt}{\sqrt{(t^2+i)(t^2-i)}} $$
that is an [incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). We get a series expansion of some definite integrals by using the Taylor series of $\sqrt{1+z}$ and integrating it termwise; for instance:
$$ \frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}}\,dx = \phantom{}_2 F_1\left(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4};\frac{5}{4};-1\right)$$
where the RHS is a (ordinary) [hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). In general, the outcome is non-elementary.

Comment: He gave us this problem in our Calculus–I course. I don't think I know any of this elliptic integral stuff; where are these elliptic functions and hypergeometric function covered in mathematics? And why doesn't this function turn out to be any simple-regular sort of integrals we have usually?